# Prevent "There are multiple dependencies with different sources" using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I use a combination of own and external pods in several projects. If I'm developing or updating a pod, I use a Podfile.local to avoid versioning/tagging every single change. The issue here, if that I must update Podfile to comment out every pod I'm using in Podfile.local to avoid errors.

Is there any way of telling cocoapods that should consider Podfile.local over Podfile when both files have the same pod to prevent this errors:

> Analyzing dependencies [!] There are multiple dependencies with
>   different sources for `Analytics` in `Podfile`:
>
> - Analytics (HEAD)
> - Analytics (from `~/Documents/analytics_ios`)

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'http://gitlab.whatever.com/podfolder/cocoapods_ios.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

# Allows per-dev overrides
local_podfile = "Podfile.local"
eval(File.open(local_podfile).read) if File.exist? local_podfile

pod 'Advertising/Dfp', :head
pod 'RSSParser', :head
pod 'DTCoreText'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'OurKeyboard', :head
pod 'VideoPlayer/GooglePrerollForAdMob', :head
pod 'Analytics', :head
pod 'AppVersioning', :head
```

My Podfile.local:

```
pod 'Analytics', :path => '~/Documents/analytics_ios'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Podfile.local` trick is no longer possible since CocoaPods 0.35 and was never officially supported.
See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2860

Comment: I found this question on Google while trying to figure out how to do dev on a CocoaPod.  Would you be able to explain the canonical way to do this now?  Pretty much all the Google hits talk about the old way.

Comment: @MattMc No way now, but as the saying goes "we accept pull-requests." ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This same issue occurred when installing pod in **Watch extension**  in existing application in Configuration :- **Swift-3,Xcode-8.1 and Pod-version 1.0.1**.

**Existing Podfile With above error** :

> ```
> platform :ios, ‘10.0’ source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
> use_frameworks!
>
> target "DemoApp" do
>         pod 'SwiftQRCode'
>         pod 'Alamofire'
>
>
> post_install do |installer|
>     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>         config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3'
>       end
>     end  
> end
>
> target 'WatchExtension' do 
> platform :watchos, '2.0'
> pod 'Alamofire' 
> pod 'SwiftyJSON' 
> end
> ```
>
> `pod install`

[image]

Solution:

**Create the shared definition which can be shared between main app bundle and watch OS extension :-**

> ```
> Updated podfile : source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'   
>
> #Create common defination to share the library between app and extension
>
> def shared_pods    
> pod'Alamofire'   
> pod 'SwiftyJSON'  
> end
>
> target "DemoApp" do
>         platform :ios, '10.0'
>         use_frameworks!
>         shared_pods
>
>    post_install do |installer|
>       installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>           config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3'
>         end
>       end  
>  end
>
> target 'WatchExtension' do 
>      platform :watchos, '2.0'
>      use_frameworks!
>      shared_pods
> end
> ```

**So, Change in podfile has resolved above issue of "*multiple dependencies with different sources....*".**

Need to update **Library search path** :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had two same packages. One was deprecated other one was new just installed by me, but I didn't uninstall the deprecated package. So the new package was adding one dependency to my Podfile and the deprecated package was adding same the dependency, but from different source. I'd to uninstall the deprecated package and the error has gone.

Comment: How your Podfile looks like and what is the name of the package that you want to install? Open your Podfile and check if there is already installed such package and if it is, you must uninstall it and install the new one